# How can I set async for setTimeout in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, settimeout

```js
    const delayTime = (time) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("run after:", time);
      }, time);
    
    const runTime = async () => {
      await delayTime(1000);
      await delayTime(900);
    };
    
    runTime();
```

**And actual result is:**

run after: 900
run after: 1000

**And expected result I want:**

run after: 1000
run after: 900

Comment: Wrap delayTime in a promise: `const delayTime = time => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('run after:', time);
      resolve();
    }, time);
  });
};`

Comment: and resolve promise with setTimeout

Comment: Why do we need add new Promise. I think setTimeout&Interval is a Promise. I'm confusing about it. Can you explain for me, thank you ^^

Comment: @LuânNguyễnThế No, `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` do not create a promise

Comment: I got it, thank you^^

Answer (score 4):

[Async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) works with promises under the hood, so you need to return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from your `delayTime` function.

The `Promise` constructor accepts an executor function that is run synchronously (ie. immediately) with two callback functions as arguments: one to resolve the promise and another to reject the promise.

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` were added to JavaScript years before promises were widely understood, and are therefore not immediately compatible with promises: you need to "promisify" them.

To promisify a `setTimeout` expression you wrap it in a promise executor function and call the `resolve` callback function from inside the `setTimeout` callback .

```js
const delayTime = (time) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("run after:", time);
        resolve(); 
    }, time));
    
const runTime = async () => {
    await delayTime(1000);
    await delayTime(900); 
};
    
runTime();
```

Comment: Doesn't using resolve make the `DelayTime`  synchronous? and why Pollute the async/await with promises? The whole point of using async/await is to act as an alternate to the promises pattern.

Comment: If you're correct then I suppose your answer will be upvoted and selected as the answer.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan No, using `resolve()` does not make the function synchronous. Async-await is just a syntactic abstraction of promises, it only works with promises and if the function you're calling doesn't return a promise (which `setTimeout` doesn't, it uses a callback) you have to wrap it in your own promise.

Comment: It's so clear. I got it, thank youuu^^

Comment: Firstly if a function declared async doesn't return a promise, it will implicitly be wrapped in a promise[ mdn ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#:~:text=Async%20functions%20always%20return%20a%20promise.%20If%20the%20return%20value%20of%20an%20async%20function%20is%20not%20explicitly%20a%20promise%2C%20it%20will%20be%20implicitly%20wrapped%20in%20a%20promise.) you don't have  to wrap it.

Comment: Secondly, when you resolve a promise immediately after the call, the delay(the supposed time in the future) is finished, Hence a synchronous function. Plus it is very obvious that async/await is syntactical sugar over promises.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan But `setTimeout` is not an async function, so it does not return a promise. Even if you `resolve` a promise immediately, that just adds it to the event queue and the following code only gets executed once the thread is free and starts to process the event queue, meaning it's still asynchronous. That isn't even what's happening here though since `resolve()` is called in the callback to `setTimeout()`, i.e. **not** immediately.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan To clarify some things... in Ben's code, `delayTime` isn't an `async` function, so it doesn't return a Promise automatically. Marking it as `async` will return a Promise that resolves immediately, as there is no `await` used within the function `delayTime`. That's why the call to `setTimeout()` has been wrapped in a `new Promise()`, so that we can return a Promise that only resolves once the asynchronous timeout is complete. The `await`s in `runTime` function are responsible for waiting for each Promise to resolve before it continues with the rest of the function execution.

Comment: @Lennholm Please do read Ben's answer. The async function in question is not `setTimeout` but rather 'timeDelay', what is the `await` operator used against? The `timeDelay` creates a Promise that is resolved after 1000ms because of the `setTimeout` and the second call is called after 900ms the after the first call is resolved. making the whole execution time is  1900ms making it, hence synchronous. You can add `window.performance.now()`  to time stamp the execution. I have shared a sample code for you to play with, below

Comment: const delayTime = (time) =>
      new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("run after:", time);
        resolve();
      }, time));
    
    const runTime = async () => {
        const t1 = window.performance.now()
      await delayTime(1000);
         const t2 = window.performance.now()
      await delayTime(900);
         const t3 = window.performance.now()
        console.log('time from first delay  call', t2-t1)
         console.log('time from first delay  call', t3-t1)
    };
    
    runTime();

Comment: @Lennholm  Thank you for bringing up the event queue, if the execution was added to the call stack then add any `console.log` after the `timeDelay` is called and see if they execute after those calls or before and you'll know if it is synchronous or not.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan `delayTime` is indeed asynchronous but it does **not** as you claim resolve after 1000ms unless you *promisify* `setTimeout` and await that. If you don't do that, it will resolve immediately because it doesn't have anything to await. Simply calling `setTimeout()` doesn't magically make `delayTime` wait for it. Just try it for yourself, run Ben's code and see that it works as desired. Then remove the wrapping promise from `setTimeout` and see that it no longer does.

Comment: @Lennholm  `Simply calling setTimeout() doesn't magically make delayTime wait for it` . The`delaytime` function is called with await, it will be automatically wrapped in promise(shared mdn link above) or why even use async/await if you're going to promise?  and I don't claim it executes in 1000 ms. just run the sample code I shared above, and measure the time for the execution of the first call i.e t2-t1.

Comment: If `delayTime` is asynchronous, just add any log after the call. The messages should come before the  `run after:` message because `setTimeout` will delay `delayTime`  from being completed. Verify yourself if it is truly asynchronous.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan *"I don't claim it executes in 1000 ms"* – You previously wrote _"timeDelay creates a Promise that is resolved after 1000ms because of the setTimeout"_, so you **did** claim that. Ben's code does that **only** because the `setTimeout()` was promisified. Your suggestion that the promise that wraps the `setTimeout()` shouldn't be there would result in the `delayTime` not waiting for the 1000ms timeout and instead resolve immediately.

Comment: @Lennholm Again I don't claim It. it is an axiomatic fact. Run the logs with Timestamps and calculate the execution time. if it is different then let me know.

-Cheers.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan You mean the code you posted as a comment? You do realize you have promisified the `setTimeout()` call just like Ben's answer, right? If I remove that promise like you suggested, I do get a different result, yes.

Comment: @Lennholm  Yes, it is Ben's answer with time stamps logged out to the console because we're measuring the time execution of `timeDelay`.  It takes 100ms for the first and 900ms for the second call. You can use the same method for timestamping my answer. You'll see that the execution time from the first call is 1ms because it is asynchronous. Don't know what you're trying to achieve by removing and adding promises.

Comment: Correction, it is 0.1ms because the logs are called immediately after calls for `timeDelay` because it doesn't wait for the calls to end(which would be synchronous).

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan You appear to be confusing sequential vs parallel with synchronous vs asynchronous. It is possible to have an asynchronous _sequence_ of events that do not all run in parallel. Here, an asynchronous wait of 1000ms occurs, followed by an asynchronous wait of 900ms. “Asynchronous” in this contact means the main thread of execution is not blocked by these delays.

Answer (score 1):

It's more logical to have timeout function separately, and call action (`log`) in caller function:

```js
// Timeout function
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Caller function
const test = async () => {
  // Do all stuff here
  console.log(`starting...`);
  await timeout(3000);
  console.log(`3 sec passed...`);
  await timeout(5000);
  console.log(`8 sec passed, finishing.`);
}

// Run test
test();
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason your you see 900 hundred printed earlier is that the time out set for `setTimeout` is not constant. 900 milliseconds pass faster than 1000 millisecs, so hence 900 is printed earlier.

I have changed the method to pass the time-out delay with the respective message. Here is the implementation:

```js
  const delayTime = ( delay, displayMessage) =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("run after:", displayMessage );
          }, delay);
        
        const runTime = async () => {
          await delayTime(1000, '1000');
          await delayTime(1000, '900');
        };
        
        runTime();
```

Comment: Yah, but I wanna try async/await in the different time, thank you ^^

Comment: Then the order will change, why expect it to be the way you wanted?

Comment: This doesn't do what OP is after, it should log `1000`after ~1s and then log `900` after 900m/s. The use of `async`/`await` here is inncorrect, as you should only use `await` on a thenable (ie: a Promise), using it on something that isn't a thenable doesn't do much (you'll see that if you remove async/await you'll get the same result). At the moment your code queues two timeouts in parallel that then complete and execute at the same time.

Comment: @NickParsons is that possible? to have a message with a delay of 900ms display before a message with a delay of 1000 ms?  I gave him an answer for why his code didn't give the expected output and changed it to how that can be achieved. Not sure if what he is trying to do is achievable in reality

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan My understanding is that the goal is for it to wait 1000ms and then log `1000`, after that, it should then wait 900ms, and then log `900`. I'm mainly pointing out though that there is no need for you to use `async`/`await` here in your example code.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan Yes of course it's possible, Ben Aston's answer accomplishes this

Comment: @Lennholm The real question here is what Ben's code is doing. It gives a synchronous answer to what the OP asked.  I'm not here to compare answers though and sure, we can definitely programmatically make 1000ms pass before 900ms.

Comment: @Lennholm and if I had to compare then mixing promises with async/await is a bad practice and I don't think any production code has ever adopted both simultaneously.

Comment: why are you awaiting delay time? That makes no sense. You dont have to use async await at all in your code

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Yeah, but so does the question. I assume the `delayTime` does something asynchronous but definitely don't need it for just a `setTimeout`.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan Ben's answer accomplishes what the OP is asking for, i.e. it calls `delayTime`, then waits for it to resolve which it does after 1000ms, THEN it calls `delayTime` again and waits for it to resolve, which it now does after 900ms. This wouldn't be possible unless `setTimout` had been promisified. In OPs question, and in your answer, both timeouts run in parallell and because of that you have no way of making sure the first one completes before the second one.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan It's nonsense that you couldn't use explicit promises and async-await in the same code. Async-await is for handling existing promises but if you're working with an asynchronous process that is not promise based (such as `setTimeout`) you're simply forced to promisify it by wrapping it in your own promise in order to be able to use it with async-await, if that's what you want.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan (cont) It's sometimes considered bad practice to mix async-await with promises **in the same function**, because if you use explicit promises, there's really no reason to use async-await in that same function but some people do that anyway for consistency and to help with static code analysis.

Comment: `it calls delayTime, then waits for it to resolve which it does after 1000ms, THEN it calls delayTime again and waits for it to resolve, which it now does after 900ms` How is this asynchronous? its beyond me.

Comment: why does it have to be asynchronous? Where do you get that from?

Comment: Using a pattern is for just function and changing it across other areas of the project is something I have  never seen, feel free to do it on yours. But maybe read a bit about code consistency, people(maybe those I have interacted with) think it is important.

Comment: If you're using code which has callbacks and you want to use async/await in your code base you wont have much of a choice. And it makes your code base consistent, doesn't it?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze My brain is fried , I'm not sure. On a lighter note, isn't the whole point of consistency that you can't do things the way you want to because you just can't? I guess at that point you're stuck with what you have opted for.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan _"How is this asynchronous?"_ – Because it **waits** for the timeout to finish before it executes the subsequent lines of code. In the meantime, the JS thread (JS is single-threaded) is free to run other code. If it was synchronous, the JS thread would be frozen until the timeout completes.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of asynchronous that code doesn't wait for online of code to finish? 'If it was synchronous, the JS thread would be frozen until the timeout'.  That is what I am pointing out.  That the thread waits for 1000ms and then executes the second call, which makes it wait for 900ms. The total wait in an asynchronous execution should be  1000 for this example because while the thread waits for  1000ms it can attend to the second call and can start it, not wait 1000ms to do that.

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan It's quite simple, if you need a promise but don't have one, you have to create one. That doesn't make it inconsistent. You have to think of the handling of promises and the creation of promises as two separate things. Async-await only handles promises, sure it creates a promise implicitly when a function is declared as `async` but this promise doesn't accomplish anything unless there's an existing promise that controls the execution of code.